# SystemUpdate(false) not able to retain Modified fields

Tags: 2007, development

I am using `SystemUpdate(false)` in my code block and was not able to retain the modified values for a document library (both folders and files) when I am trying to rename the folder or file. Please have a look at the code:

```
Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

spItem = Web.Lists["MydocumentLibrary"].GetItemById(itemID);
//string tempFName = string.Empty;
tempFName = spItem.DisplayName;
//spItem["Name"] = ReplaceIllegalCharacters(values["DocLibItemName"].ToString().Trim());
if (spItem.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.File)
{
    //When we try to rename file name having period(dot), part of the text after dot terminates.
    //To overcome this issue we are appending some text "._" at the end of the filename [CQ:profs00032447]
    spItem["Name"] = ReplaceIllegalCharacters(values["DocLibItemName"].ToString().Trim() + "._");
}
else
{
    spItem["Name"] = ReplaceIllegalCharacters(values["DocLibItemName"].ToString().Trim());
}

// spItem.Update();
// spItem["Modified"] = spItem.File.TimeLastModified;

spItem.SystemUpdate(false);

Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Am I missing something or do I need to CheckOut files and then use SystemUpdate and later CheckIn the files?

Comment: For your information , this is not an eventhandler I am populating mine data in Gridview and trying to edit(Rename File / Folder) it from there..

Comment: Have a look at the SO question [How can “Modified By” be changed when using RunWithElevatedPrivileges?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776579/how-can-modified-by-be-changed-when-using-runwithelevatedprivileges). Might be useful.

Comment: I edited your question to say "modified value" instead of "field" as I think that's what you mean - the modified values are changing when you want them to stay the same? If that's wrong, please edit the question to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate values which you might be trying to modify; the name of the file itself; or the name of the file as stored by the list item.

If it is the latter - this is stored as the Title field - `spItem["Title"]`; if it's the former then you will need to change it on the `spItem.File` object. I think you may be changing a different value to what you expect to be changing, by changing the `"Name"` value.